# confusion in a wording a problem regarding the expectation of a rv

Tags: probability

We roll a fair dice repeatdly. Let $X$ be the number of rolls needed to obtain a $5$ and $Y$ the number of rolls needed to obtain a $6$. Find $E(X|Y=2)$.

So, we want

$$ E(X|Y=2) = \sum_x \frac{x p_{XY}(x,2)}{p_Y(2)} $$

now, by the way I understand the problem $X,Y$ their range is $\{1,2,3,4,... \}$. so we need first

$$ p_y(2) = P(Y=2) = { ? \choose 2 } (1/6)^2(5/6)^{?-2}$$

now this looks like bernoulli, but Im confused about the sample size. what sample size $?$ should we take?

Comment: Not following.  You just want the probability that you get the first $6$ on the second trial?  So, the probability that first trial is a non-$6$ and the second trial is a $6$, yes?

Comment: I feel so stupid now. So this is just geometric I get confused by the wording

Comment: so $P(y=2) = \frac{5}{36}$

Comment: Yep, it's a geometric, and that's the correct probability for getting the first 6 on the 2nd roll.

Comment: So, for instance, we also have $$ P(X=x \cap Y=2) = (5/6)^{x-1} 1/6 \times 5/36 $$ that correct}

Answer (score 1):

No, no, the experiment is not constructed from Binomial Distributions, but rather Geometric.

$p_{\small Y}(y) = (5/6)^{y-1}(1/6)~[1\leq y]$ is the probability for obtaining no `6` before roll $y$ and `6` on roll $y$.

Similarly the probability for obtaining the firsts `5` and `6` on rolls $x$ and $y$ will be:

$$p_{\small X,Y}(x,y) =\begin{cases} (4/6)^{x-1}(1/6)(5/6)^{y-x-2}(1/6) &:& 1\leq x<y\\(4/6)^{y-1}(1/6)(5/6)^{x-y-2}(1/6)&:& 1\leq y<x\\ 0 &:&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

So, now evaluate $p_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid 2)=\begin{cases} ? &:& x=1 \\ ? &:& 2<x\\ 0 &:& \textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- If $Y=2$ then $X \not = 2$
- $E[X\mid Y=2]  $ $=\frac{P(X=1, Y=2)\, E[X\mid Y=2, X=1]+P(X>2 , Y=2)\, E[X\mid Y=2, X>2]}{P(Y=2)}$
- $E[X\mid Y=2, X=1] = 1$
- $E[X\mid Y=2, X>2] = 2+E[X]$